# Azure Notebook service shows error when opening nobteook: "Error loading notebook"

Tags: azure, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to open a notebook: "index.ipynb"

[image]

---

When I click on the notebook, I receive this error:

[image]

---

I tried to restart my notebook server:

[image]

---

I click restart, I'm taken to this page:

[image]

---

Every time I click restart, I'm taken back to the above page.

So, I try to click on "connecting to it again" and get the following:

[image]

---

So, I'm stuck.  I can't open a notebook and I can't restart the backend.

I'm guessing this will need to be fixed by the Azure Engineering Team, but I'm raising it here in case other users run into this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work for Azure Notebooks. Could you [open an issue on GH](https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureNotebooks/issues) - make sure to include a link to your (public) notebook?